# How to make layout for Android app intended for wearables with api under 20

Tags: android, layout, watch, responsibility

I bought cheap Chinese Android watch with Android 4.4.2, API 19. I would like to create an app which would work on the watch as well as android phones. The problem is that if I put some special layout into layout-watch folder, this qualifier does not work since it can be used only with minimal API version 20. Also, If I write something like this:

```
if(conf.uiMode == conf.UI_MODE_TYPE_WATCH) {
```

it returns false and behaves like non-watch device. Could you please give me some hints how to create "watch app" for this kind of devices which should also work on API 20+ ? How to specify special layout for wearables/watches ? How to write a condition which can determine if current device is a wearable device/watch ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```
public static boolean isWatch(Activity activity) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        Configuration conf = activity.getResources().getConfiguration();
        return conf.uiMode == conf.UI_MODE_TYPE_WATCH;
    } else {
        if(UIUtil.getDisplayWidth(activity)<320||UIUtil.getDisplayHeight(activity)<320) {
            return true; //Some dump Chinese watch
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```